# elisp: defmacro with lambda

Tags: emacs, elisp

Sorry, I tried few times and I can't build simple `defmacro` - can anybody help me with that:

So, I want define macro which will expand to:

```
(define-key keymap "*" (lambda ()
                          (interactive)
                          (some-func "*")))
```

I tried something like:

```
(defmacro wrap-and-define-key (keymap key func)
  `(define-key ,keymap ,key (lambda () (interactive) (,func ,key))))
```

And it works with:

```
(wrap-and-define-key keymap key func)
```

but doesn't work with

```
(wrap-and-define-key keymap key 'func)
```

How to change defmacro statement to make last form working? Thanks!

Comment: Why does it need to be a macro? Just define an ordinary function.

Comment: @barmar yea, it's seems to be simplier and more useful solution. Btw, i  just tried to learn a bit about defmacro here. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this.

```
(defun wrap-and-define-key (keymap key func)
  (define-key keymap key (lambda () (interactive) (funcall func key))))
```

(Don't quote lambda forms. Avoid `eval`.)

Not sure why you want this, but anyway, this should do what you ask.

Comment: While I agree, I think it's important to point out that your code will only work in lexical binding mode.  I.e. you need `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-` somewhere on the first line of the file that holds this code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your macro doesn't work for the second example is `'func` is passed as the argument with the quote, since arguments to macros are not evaluated automatically. So the lambda in the macro expands to:

```
(lambda () (interactive) ('func key))
```

But you cannot quote a function name when it is invoked in this way. Only a lambda or an unquoted symbol can appear as the first item in a function invocation expression. If you change the macro to this:

```
(defmacro wrap-and-define-key (keymap key func)
  `(define-key ,keymap ,key (lambda () (interactive) (funcall ,func ,key))))
```

It will work. When the lambda is invoked, `'func` gets evaluated to the plain func symbol and passed to funcall. funcall then looks up the symbol in the function namespace (Elisp is a *Lisp-2*) and invokes it.

As suggested in another answer, you can accomplish this with a function. This function will work regardless of whether lexical mode is enabled:

```
(defun wrap-and-define-key (keymap key func)
  (define-key keymap key `(lambda () (interactive) (funcall ',func ,key))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find something working but not sure - that is elegant solution:

```
(defmacro wrap-and-define-key (keymap key func)
  `(define-key ,keymap ,key '(lambda () (interactive) (eval (list ,func ,key)))))
```